# Can I apply for a 10 year UK visa?

Tags: uk, passports, standard-visitor-visas, long-term, egyptian-citizens

over my latest 2-year UK visa, I traveled 4-5 times to UK. My son is a permanent resident in the UK. Im applying for a new UK visa and only 3 years are left in my passport before it expires. Can I apply for a 10 year UK visa? I am a female Egyptian University professor. I am over 60 years old.

Comment: `Can I apply for a 10 year UK visa?` Yes you can. The years left on your current passport is more than enough.

Comment: As far as I know there’s nothing to stop you applying for a 10 year visit visa with a passport expiring in 3 years  https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa You can apply online to transfer your visa if you wish to when the time comes, or travel with your expired and new passport https://www.gov.uk/transfer-visa

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: You can always *apply*. That won't mean you'll get it of course.